# Item duplicated in RecyclerView after application call onStart

Tags: java, android

Every time the application is destroyed and opened again, by another mean every time the method "onStart" is called, every new item added two times.
And when I close it and open it again, every new item will be repeated three times , and so on...

Here is the code of the activity :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        IntializeControllers();
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("userID" ) != null&& getIntent().getStringExtra("userName") != null&& getIntent().getStringExtra("userImage") != null){
            messageReceiverID = getIntent().getExtras().get("userID").toString();
            if (messageReceiverID.equals(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                Toast.makeText(this, "يرجى التأكد من إعدادات تسجيل الدخول", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            messageReceiverName = getIntent().getExtras().get("userName").toString();
            messageReceiverImage = getIntent().getExtras().get("userImage").toString();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "لا يوجد بيانات", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        DisplayLastSeen();
        userName.setText(messageReceiverName);
        Picasso.get().load(messageReceiverImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(userImage);
        SendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessage();
                MessageInputText.setText("");
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                   mCurrentPage++;
                   itemPos =0;
                   LoadMoreMessages();
            }
        });
        sendFileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                        {
                                "Images",
                                "PDF Files",
                                "Ms Word Files"
                        };
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select the File");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        if (i == 0){
                            checker ="image";
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"),438);
                        }if (i == 1){
                            checker ="pdf";
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("application/pdf");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select PDF File"),438);
                        }if (i == 2){
                            checker ="docx";
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("application/msword");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Ms Word File"),438);
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        seenListener =null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LoadMessages();
        callImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               sheckSelfPermissionsAndCallUser();
           }
       });
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

 private void IntializeControllers() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.group_chat_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View actionBarView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_chat_bar, null);
            actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        }

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        messageSenderID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        callImage = findViewById(R.id.custom_user_call);
        userImage = findViewById(R.id.custom_profile_image);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.custom_profile_name);
        userLastSeen = findViewById(R.id.custom_user_last_seen);
        SendMessageButton = findViewById(R.id.send_message_btn);
        MessageInputText = findViewById(R.id.input_message);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.private_messages_list_of_users);
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        sendFileButton = findViewById(R.id.send_files_btn);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatActivity.this);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate =currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        saveCurrentTime =currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder()
                .context(this)
                .applicationKey("b3ecda78-59b0-400e-91bb-53f14fc1efc1")
                .applicationSecret("pi0eQwXOzEGP7Crsk8Zepw==")
                .environmentHost("clientapi.sinch.com")
                .userId(firebaseUser.getUid())
                .build();

        sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        sinchClient.start();
        callImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userLastSeen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        sinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new CallClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, final com.sinch.android.rtc.calling.Call calli) {
                 alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("وردتك مكالمة من قبل " + messageReceiverName);
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "رفض", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        call.hangup();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "قبول", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        call = calli;
                        call.answer();
                        call.addCallListener(new sinchCallListenr());
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Calling is Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
       apiService = Client.getClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").create(APIService.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 438 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){

            progressDialog.setTitle("Sending File");
            progressDialog.setMessage("please wait, we are sending that file...");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();
          fileUri = data.getData();

          if (!checker.equals("image")){
              StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Document Files");

              final String messageSenderRef = "Messages/" + messageSenderID +"/" + messageReceiverID;
              final String messageReceiverRef = "Messages/" + messageReceiverID + "/" +messageSenderID;

              DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = RootRef.child("Messages")
                      .child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).push();

              final String messagePushID =userMessageKeyRef.getKey();

              final StorageReference filePath =storageReference.child(messagePushID +"."+checker);

              filePath.putFile(fileUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                      if (task.isSuccessful()){
                          filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                              @Override
                              public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                  final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                                  myUrl = downloadUrl;
                                  notify = true;
                                  Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
                                  messageTextBody.put("message",myUrl);
                                  messageTextBody.put("name", Objects.requireNonNull(fileUri.getLastPathSegment()));
                                  messageTextBody.put("type",checker);
                                  messageTextBody.put("from",messageSenderID);
                                  messageTextBody.put("to",messageReceiverID);
                                  messageTextBody.put("seenMessage",false);
                                  messageTextBody.put("messageID",messagePushID);
                                  messageTextBody.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
                                  messageTextBody.put("date",saveCurrentDate);

                                  Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
                                  messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef 
+"/" +messagePushID, messageTextBody);

messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef +"/" +messagePushID, 
messageTextBody);   RootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails);
                                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                                  if (notify) {
                                     // 
sendNotification(messageReceiverID, GetNameUser(), myUrl, checker);
                                  }
                                  notify = false;
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  }
              }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                      Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                      double p = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                      progressDialog.setMessage((int) p +" % Uploading....");
                  }
              });
          }else if (checker.equals("image")){
              StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Image Files");

              final String messageSenderRef = "Messages/" + messageSenderID +"/" + messageReceiverID;
              final String messageReceiverRef = "Messages/" + messageReceiverID + "/" +messageSenderID;

              DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = RootRef.child("Messages")
                      .child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).push();

              final String messagePushID =userMessageKeyRef.getKey();

              final StorageReference filePath =storageReference.child(messagePushID +".jpg");
              uploadTask = filePath.putFile(fileUri);
              uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                  @Override
                  public Object then(@NonNull Task task){

                      if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                          Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, ""+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                      return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                  }
              }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>(){
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                      if (task.isSuccessful()){
                          Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                          myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                          Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
                          messageTextBody.put("message",myUrl);
                          messageTextBody.put("name",fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
                          messageTextBody.put("type",checker);
                          messageTextBody.put("from",messageSenderID);
                          messageTextBody.put("to",messageReceiverID);
                          messageTextBody.put("seenMessage",false);
                          messageTextBody.put("messageID",messagePushID);
                          messageTextBody.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
                          messageTextBody.put("date",saveCurrentDate);

                          Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
                          messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef +"/" +messagePushID, messageTextBody);
                          messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef +"/" +messagePushID, messageTextBody);


                          RootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                              @Override
                               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                      notify=true;
                                      //messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                                      Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Message Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                      if (notify) {
                                         sendNotification(messageReceiverID, GetNameUser(), myUrl, checker);
                                      }
                                      notify = false;
                                  }else {
                                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                                      Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error : "+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  }
                              }

                          });
                      }
                  }
              });
          }else {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing Selected, Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              progressDialog.dismiss();
          }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d("tester","onResume");

        super.onResume();
        //move recycler from here
        messageAdapter =new MessageAdapter(messagesList,ChatActivity.this,messageReceiverImage);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new
                ItemTouchHelper(new SwipeToDeleteCallback(messageAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
        seenMessage();
        UpdateUserStatus("online");
        DisplayLastSeen();
        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //    messagesListAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter(messagesList,messageReceiverImage);
  //      recyclerView.setAdapter(messagesListAdapter);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("tester","onStop");
        FirebaseUser  firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null){
            UpdateUserStatus("offline");
           RootRef.removeEventListener(seenListener);
            RootRef.removeEventListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("tester","onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        FirebaseUser  firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null){
            UpdateUserStatus("offline");
            if (seenListener != null) {
                RootRef.removeEventListener(seenListener);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate your help as I can't figure out the problem. Please note that a lot of functions have been removed for readability.

Comment: It is because onStart is being called everytime your activity view is recreated. Since you have your loading setup in onStart() this makes the data appear as many times as it has been onStart(). Read more about activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, clear adap zter while loading new data, so duplicacy can be removed and update new data. This issue occur due to multiple call on Android Lifecycle method in various state like

**onResume** - Called multiple times. So avoid initalization in here

**onStart** - is called whenever application is come from background to foreground or visible state

```
// When adding new data
adapter.addAll(data);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

// when updating data again in onResume or onStart
adapter.clear();// clear old data from list
adapter.addAll(data);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//Inside adapter
//Adding item
void addAll(List<Data> data){
list.addAll(data);
}

//For clearing list
void clear(){
list.clear();
// To update list automatically add below line
//notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```